# The proper way to setup relationship models in Eloquent repository setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to figure out how to create user roles using model relationships when a user gets created from admin in my app.

I have the following tables:

**users**

The `users` table holds a list of users.

**users_roles**

The `users_roles` table is a pivot table that links `roles` to `users`.

**roles**

The `roles` table contains a list of roles.

I am trying to use a repository setup so that my controller has no mention of eloquent.

This is my controller:

```
class ContractorController extends Controller
{
    private $user;

    /**
     * Create a new instance.
     *
     * @return Middleware
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepoInterface $user, TimesheetRepoInterface $timesheet)
    {
        $this->middleware('actions');

        $this->user = $user;
        $this->timesheet = $timesheet;
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
    {
        // create user
        $user = $this->user->createUser($request->except('_token'));

        // user was created above so we can use $user object
        $this->user->createUserRole($user);

        return Redirect::back()->withMessage('New user created.');
    }
}
```

My repository:

```
/**
 * Create new user role.
 *
 * @param $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function createUserRole($user)
{
    return $this->user->roles()->attach($user);
}
```

My User model:

```
/**
 * Get the roles associated with the user.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\UsersRoles', 'users_roles', 'role_id', 'user_id');
}
```

The above code results in a record getting created in the `users_roles` table which is correct, however I do not know how to associate the correct role_id in the table.

Here is the data that gets inserted into `users_roles`:

```
id    user_id    role_id
1     1          0
```

As you can see there is no role_id because i'm not sure how I can pass this in.  I know that if I was phsically creating a new role in the `roles` table, then I coud use this object.  But the role already exists so I just need to associate this new user with a role that I specify.

Please can someone point me in te direction of how I can do this or how would I have to adjust my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your pivot table `users_roles` should be singular and alphabetical. e.g. `role_user`.

Comment: Yes but I am already providng the name of the table in my `belongsToMany` method.  Also, I am using the `attach()` method, see code above.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing roles array not user array

```
$this->user->createUserRole($user);
```

instead of this it should be the roles you want to attach with the user

```
$this->user->createUserRole($roles);//$roles array
```

Comment: Ok but if I do this, then the user_id is blank in the users_roles table

Comment: How can I attach the user_id as well?

Comment: You have **`roles`** relationship in your user model so when you apply **`createUserRole`** it will behind take the user_id from the model.

Comment: Tht's what I thought but I get `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'role_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users_roles` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (, 2))`

Comment: Sorry, it seems the `user_id` is the field thats not getting inserted.

Comment: You can see http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: Yes I have been reading from here all afternoon and got this far but can't figure out the final part.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do the same thing, I finally managed to get it working by sending in the user_id as well as the role_id to my repository like this:

```
$this->user->createUserRole($this->role->findRoleByName('Contractor')->id, $user->id);
```

Then in my repository I did the following:

```
/**
 * Create new user role.
 *
 * @param $role
 * @param $user
 * @return mixed
 */
public function createUserRole($role, $user)
{
    return $this->user->roles()->attach($role, ['user_id' => $user]);
}
```

This adds the `role_id` as well as the `user_id` to the `users_roles` table.